# Header menu drop down & Image not showing

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am  was running a website http://www.provaltech.com , just 2 days back it working fine, please check the cache http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.provaltech.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-beta

As, you can see in current website, I am not able to see drop downs in menus & header images. I have tried lots of things but still not able to find the solution. Can anyone help me in that, how can I solve it via wp-login.

Regards,
Umar

Comment: `TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
$("form").on("submit.jqte.jqtedefault", function (e) {`

Answer (score 0):

The sub menus have a class of 'display: none' on them and there seems to be nothing that, on hover, shows the sub-menus.

In theory there should be a CSS and/or javascript routine for showing these menu. There are no errors in the code so it looks like the routines to show/hide the menus have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Home jsp functions. You may modifed any property names there. Because, you are getting error as " Object doesn't support this property or method" in Script.js. Please check the script.js at line no 44. You may misspelled any proprty names or new property which is not available in your JSP or Form.

Hope this will helpful for debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Through css only u have to change do this, you put display:none on the submenus,so when hovering the menus sub-menu can't displayed;
U put display:block on the sub menu when hovers on the main menu.
Using main menu and sub menu id u have to do this

Or once again u have to check the Manu section in your wp-admin where the sub-pages are available or not.